# IQueryable C# Select

Tags: c#, select, iqueryable

this is my code... but i need select only column to display in my Datagridview.
I Need the code to select only some columns.. example

```
Select{t => t.usu_Login, t => t.usu_Login}

public List<tb_usuario> Get(FilterDefinition filter)
{

     var contexto = new indNET_Entities();

     IQueryable<tb_usuario> Consulta = contexto.tb_usuario.AsQueryable<tb_usuario>()
                                                        .Where(t => t.usu_Ativo == 1)
                                                        .OrderBy(t => t.usu_Login);


     return Consulta.ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want a limited number of columns and you intend to pass the result out of the method, first declare a concrete type to describe the elements.

```
public class UsuarioData
{
     public string UsuLogin { get; set; } // or whatever
     public string UsuName { get; set; }  // or whatever
}
```

Then you can use this in the return type for the method

```
public List<UsuarioData> Get(...)
```

And finally, use the type in your select.

```
var consulta = contexto.tb_usuario.Where(whatever).OrderBy(whatever)
                   .Select(t => new UsuarioData
                                {
                                     UsuLogin = t.usu_login,
                                     UsuName = t.usu_name
                                }
                           );

return consulta.ToList();
```

And, of course, your callers should expect to get this as the result (or just use type inference with `var`).

Comment: i try this code but the select show me all fields in datagridview.

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9585/aaaabw.jpg

and i select only two fields.. sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a few ways you could do this, the easiest way:

```
     grdvwHoldings.DataSource = Model.Holdings
                                .Select(x=> new 
                                            { Name= x.HoldingName, 
                                              CustomerName = x.FundCustomerName 
                                             }).ToList();
     grdvwHoldings.DataBind();
```

Alternatively you could create a class and substitute the new {} for the class and do it at the data layer level.

Answer (score 1):

```
 IQueryable<tb_usuario> Consulta = contexto.tb_usuario.AsQueryable<tb_usuario>()
                                                    .Where(t => t.usu_Ativo == 1)
                                                    .OrderBy(t => t.usu_Login)
                                                    .Select(t => t.ColumnName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(contexto.AsEnumerable() 
select new {usu_Login=r.Field<string>("usu_Login")}).ToList();
```